# Adding Crop to PHP Image Resize Script

Tags: php, crop, image-uploading

I have an existing image upload script (below) which works fine but I would like to add a crop function to it, so each uploaded photo maintains the right aspect ration, but is cropped to, say, 200 x 200px.

I have looked at other questions on SO relating to this but ideally I'd like to add cropping to my script, rather than implement a whole new one, if that makes sense.

Could anyone help?

Thanks as always.

```
mkdir("images/$user_id");
$saveto = "images/$user_id/$user_id.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
$typeok = TRUE;

switch($_FILES['image']['type'])
{
    case "image/gif":   $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto); break;

    case "image/jpeg":  // Both regular and progressive jpegs
    case "image/pjpeg": $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto); break;

    case "image/png":   $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto); break;

    default:            $typeok = FALSE; break;
}

if ($typeok)
{




    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);
    $max = 200;
    $tw  = $w;
    $th  = $h;

    if ($w > $h && $max < $w)
    {
        $th = $max / $w * $h;
        $tw = $max;
    }
    elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)
    {
        $tw = $max / $h * $w;
        $th = $max;
    }
    elseif ($max < $w)
    {
        $tw = $th = $max;
    }

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
    imageconvolution($tmp, array( // Sharpen image
                            array(-1, -1, -1),
                            array(-1, 16, -1),
                            array(-1, -1, -1)
                           ), 8, 0);
    imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($src);


}
```

EDIT: I have found the following script which works fine when its on its own page, however I'm having trouble implementing it either into or after my existing upload script - I get a few 'failed to open stream: No such file or directory' errors - however the path to the image is correct (i've echoed it out to be sure):

```
$filename = 'images/$user_id/$user_id.jpg';

// Get dimensions of the original image
list($current_width, $current_height) = getimagesize($filename);

// The x and y coordinates on the original image where we
// will begin cropping the image
$left = 25;
$top = 25;

// This will be the final size of the image (e.g. how many pixels
// left and down we will be going)
$crop_width = 200;
$crop_height = 200;

// Resample the image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_width, $crop_height);
$current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, $left, $top, $current_width, $current_height);
imagejpeg($canvas, $filename, 100);
```

Could someone help me put the two together?

Thanks

Comment: This is too localized. The answer, how to add crop to your *specific* script, won't help anybody but yourself. There are hundreds if not thousands of examples of cropping images with PHP, you should *try* to add this to your script and ask for help if you encounter an error.

Comment: [imagick::cropThumbnailImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php) will do all the job for you.

Comment: @meagar Fair point :) I'll try something and report back. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for there responses - I got my script working by changing

```
$filename = 'images/$user_id/$user_id.jpg';
```

to

```
$filename = "images/$user_id/$user_id.jpg";
```

Comment: If you don't see it. He changed the quotes!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on : [Gregwar/Image](https://github.com/Gregwar/Image)

It's very easy to use, and very efficient.

- resize($width, $height, $background): resizes the image, will
  preserve scale and never enlarge it
- scaleResize($width, $height, $background): resizes the image, will
  preserve scale
- forceResize($width, $height, $background): resizes the image, will
  orce the image to be exactly $width by $height
- cropResize($width, $height, $background): resizes the image
  preserving scale and croping the whitespaces